# Как обратиться к элементу в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть мини SPA, он тянет по AJAX небольшие массивы данных из базы: номер комнаты и ее статус.

Как можно обратиться к дочернему элементу нужного блока, номер которого мы вытащим из базы, чтоб с ним произвести какие либо манипуляции?

[Ссылка на скриншот](http://prntscr.com/uszsfm)

Суть:

При запросе и выводе номера комнаты (и его статуса), чтоб при статусе занято, перекрашивать сам цвет.

Comment: @Vasily, спасибо большое за ответ, но суть чуть чуть другая. Есть несколько комнат, и массив с их статусами и номерами.
Нужно найти в списке комнат в разметке нужный номер и сопоставив его с массивом, выдать уже закраску цветом.
За вариант спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Vasily, спасибо огромное. Ваш ответ помог!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// мок запроса
const rooms = [
{
    number: 514,
    isVacant: true
  },
  {
    number: 515,
    isVacant: false
  },
  {
    number: 516,
    isVacant: true
  },
  {
    number: 0,
    isVacant: true
  }
]

rooms.forEach(room => {
  const $target = $("[data-room-number=" + room.number + "]")
  if ($target && room.isVacant) {
    $target.css("background-color", "green")
  } else {
    $target.css("background-color", "red")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-room-number="514">514</div>
<div data-room-number="515">515</div>
<div data-room-number="516">516</div>
```